# Regular expression? How to break lines in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, line-breaks, long-lines

I'm translating an ugly formatted lang file of a plugin. It's really uncomfortable as it has no line breaks at all.

How do I enter `\n` after `}` and most of all after
`"text":"text",`

Example of what the code looks like:

```
{"dir":"ltr","editor":"Rich Text Editor","common":{".........
```

I'm new to regex and find it difficult to learn these operators :D

Comment: Search and replace `}` to `}\n` ?

Comment: Could you give an exemple input and expected output, I'm unsure to understand your requirements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me this looks like JSON. If this is the case, simply:

1. Install the JSTool plugin.
2. Paste your string/open the file containing your string.
3. Go to Plugins -> JSTool -> JSFormat.

Given this string:

```
{"glossary":{"title":"example glossary","GlossDiv":{"title":"S","GlossList":{"GlossEntry":{"ID":"SGML","SortAs":"SGML","GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language","Acronym":"SGML","Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef":{"para":"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.","GlossSeeAlso":["GML","XML"]},"GlossSee":"markup"}}}}}
```

It yields:

```
{
    "glossary" : {
        "title" : "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv" : {
            "title" : "S",
            "GlossList" : {
                "GlossEntry" : {
                    "ID" : "SGML",
                    "SortAs" : "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm" : "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym" : "SGML",
                    "Abbrev" : "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef" : {
                        "para" : "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso" : ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee" : "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach should provide you with a decent indentation as well, which should help you better make sense of what you have. Although replacing with a regular expression *will* work, the output could be slightly messy.

Comment: Oh man thanks! That's it :) Better than replacing with regex :D

After I'm done translating, should I deformat it? I've heard that affects performance of the script.

Comment: @Vioner: I am not sure on this, however, having the string in a single line *usually* reduces the size of the file, which when transmitting things tends to be a good thing. It is up to you really.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a regular expression here, just use the `Extended` mode:

Find what:    `}`

Replace with: `}\n`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Find What : `}`
- Replace with: `}\n`

Should work after enabling `Regular expression`.

Answer (score 0):

Find `}` and replace it to `}\n`.
and you wanted to check "text":"text",
so find `","` and replace to `",\n"` will work for you.

Comment: Also the thing I've been looking for. Thank you :)